# PWM Issue with arduino due (cortex-m3)

Tags: arduino, arm, cortex-m

I am using PWM on an arduino due board which uses SAM3X8E(cortex-m3) microcontroller. When I use PWM enable and disable on this board, the waveform goes analog on disabling the channel, instead of staying at 0 or 1. Please see the attached waveform. I tried the code by directly writing to registers also, but it was the same. I also tried a 4.7k pulldown resistor at pwm output, but got the same results. Please tell me how to fix it in software.

If a hardware solution is also possible with some external components, that is also ok. Scope images are attached. The blue scope output is for line 34 (PC02) and yellow for line 35 (PC03).

```
// include all arduino libraries here.. these are only accepted from ino files.
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pmc_enable_periph_clk (PWM_INTERFACE_ID) ;  // turn on clocking to PWM unit

  PWMC_ConfigureChannel (PWM, 0, 1, 0, PWM_CMR_CPOL) ; // PWM channel 0, clock = MCLK/2 = 42MHz
  PWMC_SetPeriod (PWM, 0, 700) ;  // period = 700 pwm clocks (60kHz)
  PWMC_SetDutyCycle (PWM, 0, 80*700/100) ;  // duty set to 80%
  PWMC_EnableChannel (PWM, 0) ;   // enable

  // Configure pin 34 (PC2) to be driven by peripheral B (PWM channel 0 L)
  // enable pin PC02 and PC03, they are complimentary
  PIOC->PIO_PDR = 0xC ;  // disable PIO control
  PIOC->PIO_IDR = 0xC ;   // disable PIO interrupts
  PIOC->PIO_ABSR |= 0xC ;  // switch to B peripheral

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


// From these settings, I got these numbers from the scope - 13.3us on time and 3.32us off time
//

  PWMC_EnableChannel (PWM, 0) ;   // enable
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  PWMC_DisableChannel (PWM, 0) ;   // enable
  delayMicroseconds(100);
}
```

Ans here's the scope images:

[image: scope image]

Comment: Are you sure that both CH1 and CH2 are in DC Coupling on your oscilloscope ?

Comment: yes both the channels are in dc coupling.

Comment: Why don't you just set PWM duty cycle to maximum or minimum instead of disabling?

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time to disable the channel.
Try to add a waiting loop after disabling:

```
void loop() {
  PWMC_EnableChannel (PWM, 0) ;   // enable
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  PWMC_DisableChannel (PWM, 0) ;   // disable
  while ((PWM->PWMC_SR & 1) != 0); //add this
  delayMicroseconds(100);
}
```

Comment: I tried checking the status register as you said, I get the same waveforms. the delays are redundant. It works fine even without any delay. as per the documentation, after pwm disable is done, its supposed to complete that cycle and stop. Thats what is happening here, but when it ends, the output instead of falling like a rock, it starts declining. Takes a good msec for the output to go near 0v.